# How to read a non-English language text from a text file and print it in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file which contains some Persian text, I want to read the file and calculate the number of occurrence of each word then print the calculated values. this is my code:

```
f = open('C:/python programs/hafez.txt')
wordDict ={}
for line in f:
    wordList = line.strip().split(' ')
    for word in wordList:
        if word not in wordDict:  
            wordDict[word] = 1
        else: wordDict[word] = wordDict[word]+1

print((str(wordDict)))
```

It produces results which has wrong coding format, I tried various ways to fix this but no good result! Here is part of the text that this code produces:

> {"\x00'\x063\x06(\x06": 3, "\x00,\x06'\x06E\x06G\x06": 16, "\x00'\x063\x06*\x06E\x06'\x069\x06": 1, '\x00-\x064\x061\x06': 1, .....}

Comment: What character encoding is your file in ? This is the first question you have to answer first. It could be unicode in UCS-2 encoding.

Comment: Actually I don't know! How can I find that?

Comment: Open the file in Notepad++ and look at the encoding. Similarly, if it opens in a browser look at the detected encoding in the menu. If that doesn't help learn what are the current encodings for persian, and how they are stored in binary, then look at the file in a hex editor.

Comment: The encoding is OEM 720

Comment: It is in this encoding:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_720

Comment: You can also use `uchardet` for guessing encodings, but you really should know your encoding *a priori* because there are [several byte sequences which are valid in multiple encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) and [it is not possible to interpret text without knowing its encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to deal with this, but perhaps the easiest is with `codecs.open()`. (I'm assuming you're using Python 2.7 for some of the other tricks here with `Counter` and `with`).

```
import codecs
from collections import Counter
wordDict = Counter()

with codecs.open('C:/python programs/hafez.txt','r',encoding='cp720') as f:
    for line in f:
        wordDict.update(line.strip().split())

for word, count in wordDict.most_common(): 
    print word, count
```

In Python 3, you need the parentheses with `print` (it's a function in Python 3 but a statement in Python 2), and you don't need to import `codecs` because the builtin `open()` has support for different encodings.

If your encoding isn't Code Page 720, then you need to replace that option with the abbreviation for the appropriate encoding.

This is a good opportunity to learn some about encodings. While I agree with Joel, [that no programmer should pretend that we live in a US English / ASCII world](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), the issue of encoding becomes especially pertinent when you're dealing with a non Latin alphabet on a regular basis. (Besides, ASCII isn't even enough for English -- many English words are borrowings that kept their accents, amongst other issues.) Good starting places are Joel's article ([The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)), the [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html) (including the [Unicode sandwich](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#35)), and for ease of producing said sandwich in Python 2, the [`codecs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs) module. There's also a [HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode) in the Python docs, which is easier to understand after you've read the other articles.

If you've decided to go full Python 3, then you can simple select your exact version from the listbox at the top of the documentation pages. The BDFL's [summary of the differences between Python 2 and 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html) also includes a bit on issues with Unicode and [how it's handled differently in Python 2 and 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit).

Comment: +1 for `codecs.open()`. Note: `.update()` make changes inplace, it returns None; remove the assignment. `print wordDict` prints word representions (it is not very readable on Python 2). You could print one word at a time `for word, count in wordDict.most_common(): print word, count`

Comment: @RaminZahedi : That was the error mentioned in the other comment, it's now been fixed.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- yeah, I posted a little too quickly on that one. Thanks!

Comment: @Livius now it prints nothing! just an empty line!

Comment: @RaminZahedi I've tested the current version with a non ASCII file locally (I don't have any Persian lying around, but I do have some European encodings) and it works. Did you change anything? The current setup assumes a series of lines, each containing whitespace-separated words.

Comment: @RaminZahedi I've also done a number of small improvements in the last few minutes -- make sure you're using the newest version.

Comment: @Livius now it becomes better, it changed the result not to correct persian but to sth better than previous, shouldn't I decode befor printing?

Comment: `print` automatically converts Unicode objects to the system encoding before output -- but that might not be enough depending on what your system / terminal encoding is. (I run into this problem with unprintable characters from time to time, usually as the result of an incorrect conversion between encodings.) Also, if your input encoding isn't specified correctly, then all bets are off how the output will look.

Comment: @Livius I'm using win7 and now sth weird is happening! when I run the module from IDLE it works but with wrong encoding but when I run the module from command prompt it says:File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0631' in position
1: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Your terminal doesn't support Persian characters -- [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) is a Latin based encoding. Since you're using Python 3, can just add a `file=myoutputfile` argument to your `print()` call  and redirect the output to a file, which you can then open in your favorite editor. (Of course, you have to do open the file first -- I recommend setting the encoding on the output file to `utf-8`.)

Comment: @Livius it works!! it works!! the correct encoding was: UTF-16

Answer (score 1):

I think in general you could encode your txt file with UTF-8, and read UTF-8 in python with # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- in the start part of py file.

Comment: It produced the same result as before

Comment: The coding line in a source file describes the coding of *the source file* and not of its inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the python [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) subclass for counting occurrences of words.

As for the text, python2.7 is not unicode by default. Read: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

You can use

```
for i,j in wordDict.iteritems():
    print unicode(i),j
```

Comment: it produces this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: You need to specify the encoding when converting to unicode! Yes, you can get away with not specifying it if you're using UTF-8 / ASCII, but [explicit is better than implicit](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 0):

I admit I don't know python, I'm learning it since a few days. And for the moment I'm a little confused between python 2 and 3, since it handles strings differently.

Just a tip to where to look : read your file into a string ( I don't know if you should open the file in binary mode ). Then convert it to unicode using

```
unicodestr = str.decode('cp720')
```

Comment: produced empty dictionary!

Comment: For a quick overview on the differences between Python 2 and 3, check out the ["What's Changed" document](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html).